# Bootstrap form - reducing the height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Have a form with 17 rows (each row around 2-3 controls). Copied my sample html below.

1) Have a requirement to reduce the height by half to all the controls. Beginner with Bootstrap and currently struck.

2) Also how to control the input size of the text fields.

3) Also would like to use fieldset around some controls.

Any pointer is appreciated.

Thanks,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row11">Label11:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="row11"
                            placeholder="Data 11">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row12">Label12:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="row12">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row21">Label21:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="row21"
                            placeholder="Data21">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row22">Label22:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="row22" placeholder="Data 22">
                    </div>
            </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row31">Label31:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="row31"
                            placeholder="Data31">
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row41">Label41:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="row41"
                            placeholder="Data41">
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="form-group">


                    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="row41"
                            placeholder="Data42">
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row51">Label51:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="row51"
                            placeholder="Data51">
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row61">Label61:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="row61"
                            placeholder="Data61">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row62">Label62:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="row62"
                            placeholder="Data62">
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row71">Label71:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="row71"
                            placeholder="Data71">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row72">Label72:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
    Ddown
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row81">Label81:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="row81"
                            placeholder="Data81">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row82">Label82:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
    Ddown
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row91">Label91:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="row91"
                            placeholder="Data91">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row92">Label92:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
    Ddown
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row101">Label101:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="row101"
                            placeholder="Data10-1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row10-2">Label102:</label>
                    </div>


                        <div class="col-sm-1 dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
    Ddown
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row11-1">Label111:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="row11-1"
                            placeholder="Data11-1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row11-2">Label112:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
    Ddown
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row12-1">Label121:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="row12-1"
                            placeholder="Data12-1">
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row13-1">Label131:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="row13-1"
                            placeholder="Data13-1">
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row14-1">Label141:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="row14-1"
                            placeholder="Data14-1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row14-2">Label142:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="row14-2"
                            placeholder="Data14-2">
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row15-1">Label151:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="row15-1"
                            placeholder="Data15-1">
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row16-1">Label161:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="row16-1"
                            placeholder="Data16-1">
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="row17-1">Label171:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <textarea rows="3" class="form-control" id="row17-1"
                            placeholder="Data17-1"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>


        </form>
    </div>

    <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think as a last resort you could brute force it with some CSS.  Add a class to the form like 'form-widgets-sm'.

Then in the CSS:

```
.form-widgets-sm label {
    height: 15px;
}

.form-widgets-sm input {
    height: 15px;
}
```

and adjust the heights in there (obviously the 15px is a placeholder). You may also have to modify the form-groups and/or the div columns.

While I am sure there is a more bootstrap way of doing this, this method isn't that disruptive (you add that one class to the form), and can allow you to move forward while you wait for a more bootstrap answer.

Comment: Thanks, Tried that it did changed the height but the alignment of the label is changed. Also noticed the padding (top/bottom) is 6 by default. That also needs to be reduced.

Comment: I guess i would change all the padding in the CSS as well.   The bootstrap approach (from my perspective) is to add classes to designate a feel, and to not over class (apply the hierarchy).